# Infinispan Concurrency DefaultCacheManager

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, infinispan, jgroups

I m using infinispan and initializing the DefaultCacheManager by this code lines:

```
                GlobalConfigurationBuilder gcb = new GlobalConfigurationBuilder();
                gcb.globalJmxStatistics().enabled(false).allowDuplicateDomains(true);
                gcb.transport().defaultTransport().addProperty(JGroupsTransport.CONFIGURATION_STRING,
                        configurator.getProtocolStackString());

                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.DIST_SYNC).expiration().lifespan(24l, TimeUnit.HOURS);

                builder.clustering().stateTransfer().awaitInitialTransfer(false);
                builder.clustering().hash().numOwners(2);

                cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(gcb.build(), builder.build());
```

The above snippet code is present in N war deployed inside the same application server.

So it happens that when i deploy all the war simultaneosly i get a concurrency exception executing the new DefaultManager() instruction

```
org.infinispan.jmx.JmxDomainConflictException: ISPN000034: There's already a JMX MBean instance type=CacheManager,name="DefaultCacheManager" already registered under 'org.infinispan' JMX domain.
```

this happens even if i ve specified the configuration property:

```
allowDuplicateDomains(true);
```

How can i handle correctly this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I created a [reproducer for this issue](https://github.com/slaskawi/38923855_multiple_wars) and as far as I can tell it looks OK.

Just a couple of gotchas and hints:

- Please make sure you're using the latest stable version (in this case [8.2.4.Final](http://infinispan.org/download/)).
- I suggest using [CDI extension](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#cdi_support) rather than implementing your own bootstrap and cleanup.
- If you for some reason need to create CacheManager yourself - remember to stop it when destroying beans.
- If you're using Wildfly - remember that your CacheManager is not the only one in the container (WF uses Infinispan for internal things like session replication).